# Opening a Basic Math Input Control

Tags: c++, winapi, com

I am hoping someone might be able to help me out.  My objective is to open a math input panel using C++ but the panel only opens for a split second before the program exits.  Here is what I have tried.

- cin.get();
- system("PAUSE");
- getchar();

All of the aforementioned attempts to keep the program open have resulted in the math input control window popping up but staying blank.

The code that I am using is directly from here.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd317324(v=vs.85).aspx

I am using Visual Studio Community Edition 2017 with Windows 10.

Any and all help is appreciated.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "micaut.h"
#include "micaut_i.c"
#include "atlcomcli.h"

using namespace std;



int main()
{
    CComPtr<IMathInputControl> g_spMIC; // Math Input Control

    HRESULT hr = CoInitialize(NULL);
    hr = g_spMIC.CoCreateInstance(CLSID_MathInputControl);
    hr = g_spMIC->EnableExtendedButtons(VARIANT_TRUE);
    hr = g_spMIC->Show();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: *"resulted in the math input control window popping up but staying blank"* - What did you expect instead, and why?

Comment: Your program terminates immediately. You need it to stay alive. You will need to run a message loop.

Comment: @IInspectable: I would like it to render the math input control but it only opens a blank window.  Without the pause techniques it renders the math input control but closes automatically.

Comment: @David Heffernan:  Great! I will research how to do this and report back.  Thank you.

Comment: Since you instantiated a math input panel into an STA, you have to make sure to dispatch messages so that it can function properly. You need to run a [message loop](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644928.aspx) as pointed out by David Heffernan.

Comment: Worked like a charm guys! I've never done any GUI programming in C++ so I was at a loss.  Thanks a bunch.

Comment: @David Heffernan:  I am pretty inexperienced with this site, but if you would care to post your response in the answers, I'll happily give you credit for solving the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your program shows the window but then terminates immediately. You will need to run a message loop to service the GUI.

Answer (score 0):

Synchronization in a single-threaded apartment (STA) is implemented through window messages (see [Understanding and Using COM Threading Models](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms809971.aspx)). This requires that you run a message loop in every STA thread.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <micaut.h>
#include <micaut_i.c>
#include <atlcomcli.h>

int main() {
    HRESULT hr = ::CoInitialize(NULL);

    CComPtr<IMathInputControl> g_spMIC; // Math Input Control
    if ( SUCCEEDED( hr ) ) {
        hr = g_spMIC.CoCreateInstance(CLSID_MathInputControl);
    }
    if ( SUCCEEDED( hr ) ) {
        hr = g_spMIC->EnableExtendedButtons(VARIANT_TRUE);
    }
    if ( SUCCEEDED( hr ) ) {
        hr = g_spMIC->Show();
    }

    if ( SUCCEEDED( hr ) ) {
        // Message loop for STA
        MSG msg{ 0 };
        while ( ::GetMessageW( &msg, nullptr, 0, 0 ) ) {
            // MathInputControl sends WM_USER + 2 when it should close
            if ( msg.message == ( WM_USER + 2 ) )
                break;
            ::TranslateMessage( &msg );
            ::DispatchMessageW( &msg );
        }

        ::CoUninitialize();
    }
}
```

The Math Input Control sending a `WM_USER + 2` message in response to clicking the *Close* or *Cancel* buttons is not part of the documented contract. A proper implementation would implement an [_IMathInputControlEvents](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd317349.aspx), and respond to its [Close](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd317351.aspx) event instead.